# Hints on diagnosing performance issue in OpenBSD firewall

Tags: firewall, openbsd, pf

My OpenBSD 4.6 pf firewall has started having really bad performance in the past few weeks.  I've isolated the firewall (as opposed to the WAN connection, switch, cable, etc.) as the problem, but need a hint on how to further diagnose or fix the problem.

The facts:

Normal setup is: DSL Modem -> FW Ext. NIC -> FW Int. NIC -> Switch -> Laptop

1. Normal setup described above gives only 25 Kbps!
2. Plugging the laptop straight from the DSL modem gives a 1 MBps connection (full speed, as advertised).  Therefore, the DSL connection seems to be OK.
3. Plugging the laptop directly into the firewall's internal NIC (bypassing the switch) also gives only 25 Kbps.  Therefore, the switch does not seem to be a problem.
4. I've replaced the ethernet cables, but it didn't help.
5. Here's the weird thing.  Reloading the ruleset (/sbin/pfctl -Fa -f /etc/pf.conf) causes the laptop's connection to go up to 1 Mbps (i.e. full speed) for a few minutes before it gradually degrades back down to 25Kbps again.

Any ideas on what's wrong or how I could further diagnose the problem?

Comment: Can you [edit] and post a `sudo pfctl -s info` from BSD when you get the slow down?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have a suboptimal MTU setting or incorrect autoset of this value so packets get fragmented which can cause serious performance degradation [see some hints](http://home.nuug.no/~peter/pf/en/long-firewall.html#PATHMTUDISC) 
Not sure about exact openbsd syntax but you can define packet size for ping and see if packets get fragmented gradually decreasing the value to find the largest one which does not cause fragmentation. [See this blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/ThinkThin/entry/the_importance_of_mtu) 
for example. Otherwise just try to blindly lower the MTU value with ifconfig to say 1300 and see if it has any effect. You can also calculate the value based on encapsulation, but it is probably quicker with trial/error method.